# aspx page opened with window.open doesn't fire OnInit, OnLoad events

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have an aspx page launched with the Click event of a button like this

```
void btn_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var url = "ThisPage.aspx?id=34567";
    RegisterStartupScript(place, "openPage(" + url +  ")");
}
```

this fires the javascript function

```
function openPage(url){
    window.open(url,"foo=bar"); //foo=bar is many, many window params
}
```

I have my breakpoint in

```
class ThisPage : Page
{
    override void OnInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ... //breakpoint
    }

    override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...//breakpoint
    }
}
```

The window is opened, but the html is rendered like this

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body/>
</html>
```

and the breakpoints are never met.

what's happening? I'm using VS2003

Comment: Are you really using VS **2003**, or did you mean *2013*?

Comment: What happens if you navigate directly to `ThisPage.aspx`?

Comment: 2003, unfortunately (sob!). if I go directly to `ThisPage.aspx` it happens the same, empty html

Comment: You should have a look at your inetpub\Logs folder. Maybe a configuration or authentication problem.

Comment: I can access and debug the other pages. in fact, that's how I got the `ThisPage` URI

Comment: var url = "ThisPage.aspx/?id=34567" - Why forward slash after .aspx?

Comment: If you open it directly and you also get a blank page, then something with ThisPage.aspx is wrong, I dont think that the script is your problem.